# PHP - Call a parent function from a parent function in a child instance

Tags: php, inheritance

The bar function of the A class needs to call the foo function of the A class. 
For an instance of A, $this->bar() works.
For an instance of B, $this->bar() doesn't work, it creates a loop B-foo - A-bar...

```
class A {
    function foo() {
        (...)
    }
    function bar() {
        $this->foo();
        (...)
    }
}
class B extends A {
    function foo() {
        parent::bar();
        (...)
    }
    function bar() {
        $this->foo();
        (...)
    }
}
```

I tried such workaround for the 'A' bar function, but getting error : "Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent"

```
class A{
    function bar(){
        switch ( get_class($this) )
        {
            case "A" : $this->foo() ; break;
            case "B" : parent::foo(); break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Any idea of how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `self::foo();` in `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cann use `self`

```
class A {
    function foo() {
        print __METHOD__;
    }
    function bar() {
        print __METHOD__;
        self::foo();
    }
}
class B extends A {
    function foo() {
        print __METHOD__;
        parent::bar();
    }
    function bar() {
        print __METHOD__;
        $this->foo();
    }
}
(new A)->bar();//calls  A::bar A::foo
(new A)->foo();//calls  A::foo
(new B)->bar();//calls  B::bar B::foo A::bar A::foo
(new B)->foo();//calls  B::foo A::bar A::foo
```